# How to parse the location out of a query string?

Tags: search, location

We're getting a lot of queries like "something in Boston", "something near NY", "something miami fl" and we're looking for the best way to parse this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you are looking for a way to parse out the location/city from a question?

Since words fly freely in english, the best proposal I have is that you create a table of the most common cities in the country you are interested in, and do a case-insensitive search through the text, scanning for those cities.

Made a quick test implementation using python, using wikipedia to extract a list of the cities in [usa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population) and created a fake question with a name of a city in it. The scripts reads both text from file and makes a search for a city; using:

- 275 cities in the list
- question with 145 words

Time for this is shown below:

```
real        0m0.061s
user        0m0.040s
sys         0m0.016s
```

Start with a list of the most common cities and their most common misspellings (thanks [ted-hop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)). Then use a simple strategy like

1. search for a city in a question.
2. if a city cannot be found, mark the question for manual review and add the city or the misspelling of a city to the list if found.
3. goto 1.

After a couple of iterations you should have a good list that covers most of the cities.

I can post the code if you are interested, it's a really trivial brute-force search in ~12 lines of python.

---

**Update** (since people still seams to read this posts)

Have a look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)

```
>>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
['apple', 'ape']
>>> import keyword
>>> get_close_matches('wheel', keyword.kwlist)
['while']
>>> get_close_matches('apple', keyword.kwlist)
[]
>>> get_close_matches('accept', keyword.kwlist)
['except']
```

this will probably ease the matching...

Comment: Don't forget to include all the common misspellings, too. Either that, or be prepared to do approximate matches.

Comment: most common?  So if I pick the top 100 cities that might cover 20% of the queries.  That still seems like a lot of searches through the text though.

Comment: The other alternative is to analyze the sentences from a linguistic perspective, identifying the verbs, adjectives, nouns and so on to determine which word is a city...

Comment: How do you handle the differences between "in Boston", "in Boston MA", "in Boston Massachusetts"?  I need to search at least three different iterations for each city?

Comment: If you only have 100 terms then you could generate a dfsm recognizer.  If the queries are just US or North American locations you can easily drive this to the county level (what's the equivalent in Canada and Mexico?) and have another recognizer for towns and cities.  Towns, cities and states/provinces are regular nouns and actually have a syllabic structure that people overlook.  Additionally you can construct the recognizers so that the most common cities and towns are searched for first.  So in the end you have two passes for each recognizer through the input.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of computational linguistics, you are looking for a methodology/technology called "[Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition)". There are numerous libraries, systems or solutions available that perform NER that can be found via Google, possibly for your chosen development language.